# multiple definition, already defined here

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have three simple files.
”banana.cc“

```
namespace ocr{
    int a = 5;
}
```

"apple.cc"

```
#include "banana.cc"

namespace ocr{
    int b = a;
}
```

"main.cc"

```
#include "apple.cc"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
/tmp/ccs6XmP2.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `ocr::a'
/tmp/ccEkxDgJ.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccs6XmP2.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `ocr::b'
/tmp/ccEkxDgJ.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cco0dUCm.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `ocr::a'
/tmp/ccEkxDgJ.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

after compiler insert all the #include, main.cc is like:

```
namespace ocr{
    int a = 5;
}

namespace ocr{
    int b = a;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

why this will cause redefinition?
Thank you.

Comment: You should not include `.cc` files. I assume these are part of your project / already being built as part of your executable.

Comment: Are you cross-compiling `linux` code under `Visual Studio`? I am trying to figure out the `visual-c++` tag.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Possibly the IDE is detecting the cc extension and thinking,  *I should compile and link these.* This leaves you with an `ocr::a` in banana.obj, another in apple.obj and yet another in main.obj.

Comment: I don't think it's the IDE. I suspect OP has added the files to the project _and_ `#include`d them.

Comment: However they got there, three objects are being linked. ccs6XmP2,  ccEkxDgJ, and cco0dUCm all define `ocr::a`. ccs6XmP2 and ccEkxDgJ define `ocr::b`. This lines up very well with the three cc files all being compiled and linked. This wraps around to two lessons: 1) Don't use file names that the tools (or you) could mistake as code to be compiled for header files and 2) avoid putting definitions in header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're compiling apple.cc *and* banana.cc *and* main.cc in your project.

So you're compiling this file:

```
namespace ocr{
    int a = 5;
}
```

and this file:

```
namespace ocr{
    int a = 5;
}

namespace ocr{
    int b = a;
}
```

and this file:

```
namespace ocr{
    int a = 5;
}

namespace ocr{
    int b = a;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously `ocr::a` is defined in all three files, and `ocr::b` is defined in two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment but I just want to elaborate on this, just in case there is still confusion.

If you want to share some variables between files, create a header file and declare it there.
i.e.

```
    // common.h
    namespace ocr{ int a, b; }

    // banana.cc
    #include "common.h"
    void initAppple(){
        ocr::a = 4;
    }
    // apple.cc
    #include "common.h
    void initBanana(){
        ocr::b = a;
    }
    // main.cc
    #include "common.h"
    int main(){ initApple(); initBanana(); }
```

And then when you compile main.cc, link it with apple.cc and banana.cc instead of "including" it.

`g++ main.cc apple.cc banana.cc -o output`

Note that you can't just declare and initialize separately in global scope, which is why you probably need to use a setter function such as the ones above (initApple() etc). Or use extern inside the header file and define it inside the source file.